# adding mail notification in evaluatecommand of shellcommand in buildbot

Tags: buildbot

Basically I have inherited ShellCommand to overwrite evaluatecommand.
In evaluatecommand, I parse the log and find the actual maintainer of the package to send a mail notification.

Everything other than mailnotification does not work fine.

```
    class CustomShellCommand(ShellCommand):
    command = None
    parser = None
    haltOnFailure = True
    buildername = ''
    ci = None


    def __init__(self,command, ci,  buildername, **kwargs):

        self.ci = ci

        self.command = command
        self.buildername = buildername
        ShellCommand.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        if len(self.command) > 0 and self.command[0] == 'make_isolated':
            self.parser = ParseLog()
            self.addLogObserver('stdio', self.parser)
        self.setDefaultWorkdir("build")



    def evaluateCommand(self, cmd):
        if self.parser is not None:
            self.parser.packages
            for pkg in self.parser.packages:
                emails =  get_maintainer_emails()
        if cmd.rc > 0:
            mn = add_mail_notifiers([self.buildername], emails[-1])
            self.ci.masterconfig['services'].append(mn)

            return util.FAILURE
        else:
            return util.SUCCESS
```

But when I add mail notifiers in **init** it works, but does not work in evaluate command. 
Any  pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am no buildbot expert, I just started using it 2 months ago in my new job. But here I think the MailNotifier is something related to the master, and more precisely to the config. For your `ShellCommand`, I suppose the master executes the `__init__` when it loads its config. But the `evaluateCommand` I think is only executed on runtime by the slave, and they cannot change the config of the master...

Here we have written an external script to send personalized mail for failed builds. It has a builder which triggers it once a day, early in the morning after the nightly builds have finished and before people arrive at the office. We will investigate how to do this more generally as only one of our project has this feature, the other projects' failures are summarized in a general mail sent to everyone. Maybe there is something to do with the `SetProperty`, but I cannot tell for now...